# In Java application what is faster: manipulations with int[3] or custom Triple object with three int fields?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

In my Java application what will be faster: manipulations with int[3] or with custom Triple object with three int fields?
My application handles a lot of arraylists ArrayList where int[] has three elements. Will it be faster rather to create some Triple object with three int fields, or is it still better to use arrays?

And in terms of space when I serialize ArrayList<> - would ArrayList of arrays take less space than ArrayList of my custom Triple objects?

```
 class Triple 
{
int i1;
int i2;
int i3;
Triple(int i1, int in2, int i3) {
 this.i1 = i1;
 this.i2 = i2;
 this.i3 = i3;
}
 public int getI1() { return i1;}
 public int getI2() { return i2; }
 public int getI3() { return i3}
}
```

Comment: I downvoted your question, now let me explain: 1) Your question needs to be reworded for clarification, I'm not generally easily confused, but it's hard for me to get the idea of what you need or are looking for. 2) Code would be great for your `Triple` objects because they would help determine efficiency and what it is that you need.

Comment: It seems logically, the most effiecient may be making your own Objects, but that is hard to determine with the question and lack of code. I say make your own, because you can code the methods for manipulation, but again, this is not a fantastically written question. Please revise.

Comment: Profile, then benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience, using both would basically be the same speed. If you are talking about coding speed, int[3] is the best way to go; if your application runs on integers.

IMHO, I think a Vector3i class would look better if someone were to look at your code.

Comment: No, I'm only concerned about runtime performance. I wrote with arrays, now thinking if it is wroth re-writing for speeding up. I was thinking maybe it does all the time ArrayOutofBounds checking?

Comment: Like I said, either would work. They both have similar runtime speeds.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pity. Don't know how to speed up.

Comment: what kind of reasoning is that? where are you reasons to back u up? array elements occupy consecutive locations in ram yet variables may scattered all over the ram as far as  I know. by your answer, you literally ignored OOP principals

Comment: which principles did I ignore?  I just asked.

Comment: @KickButtowski You're speaking about three loose variables while Eric speaks about Vector3i/Triple. The three fields surely occupy consecutive locations as well (not guaranteed by the JLS, but true) and there's no `length` and no bounds checks. So (apart from class loading time) it can't be slower. However, showing that it's *measurably* faster could be a challenge. What model corresponds with the OP's needs better, we don't know.

Comment: @maaartinus this question is opinion based but the answer is not sufficient which is gonna go back to my opinion ?

Comment: @KickButtowski This questions asks about speed, so there's IMHO no room for opinions. `class Triple` is (very slightly) faster and no bigger than an `int[3]`, that's my claim. If I wasn't so sure of it, I'd go and measure.